# Magento CE: Cannot assign product to some subcategories

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm having a strange bug in my Magento CE 1.9.0 Edition. If I select a product (Catalog -> Manage Products -> *Select any Product* -> Categories) I can't assign the product to all categories because in some categories no dropdown arrow appears.

To make everything a little bit more clear here are some pictures:

This is how the categories look like (In 'Brandschutzsysteme' there are many subcategories).

[image: In 'Brandschutzsysteme' there are many subcategories]

If I go to Catalog -> Manage Products -> *Select any Product* -> Categories I can't select the subcategories of 'Brandschutzsysteme' because there is no dropdown arrow.
[image]

Comment: have you indexing your data from admin ???

Comment: yes, I've indexed data and cleared the cache..